# Firemonkey: how to set the color of the prompt of a Tedit under windows?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Under Firemonkey, how to set the color of the prompt of a Tedit (under windows only) ? When the Tedit text string is empty, the Tedit displays the prompt string instead and i need to find a way to customize it's color

Comment: it's will be good for the people who down-vote the question to say why they downvote it ...

Comment: did you find a solution ? still same in news version ..

Answer (score 0):

The `TextSettings.FontColor` property controls both editable text color and prompt color, so you need to change the color depending on `Text` property being empty or not. The prompt text is shown when `Text` is empty.

For example

```
procedure TForm11.Edit1Typing(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Sender as TEdit).Text <> '' then
    (Sender as TEdit).TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Black
  else
    (Sender as TEdit).TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Crimson;
end;
```

There might be other solutions based on styles, but you did not mention them, so I chose to show you a solution without styles.

Comment: thanks tom, but seam that for the prompt the FontColor is "mixed" with the background color (maybe by adding some opacity to it).

Comment: so i would like to set the color myself :) not the dimmed, i want to set myself the color ...

Comment: You asked how to change the prompt color and I answered that question. Now you are asking for how to disable the dimming of the prompt text, which is a totally different matter. Please post a new question.

Comment: bah no, sorry red with dimming it is not red :( anyway thanks for the help !

Comment: For what it's worth 3 years later. You can change the dimming within the style. The prompt label has a default opacity of 0.5 (version 10.3.2). At the moment the only way to adjust the prompt color is by changing the fontcolor of the TEdit itself. This is a design error imho, because you can change the styling for the prompt label through the SyleDesigner, but it will just be ignored.